# Google sign in is not working in android but working in ios

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am new in flutter, In my app users can login with google. I implemented it using firebase google signin. The problem is, it is working in ios but not in android. I have checked with multiple devices, everywhere issue is same. Its like execution skips when it reaches GoogleSignInAccount in android. I will add my code below. I have added project in firebase and enabled sign in authentication and checked SHA-1 key as well. Sometime it works and sometimes it doesn't.

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<bool> signInWithGoogle() async {
  bool isLoggedIn = false;
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final UserCredential authResult =
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final User user = authResult.user;

  if (user != null) {
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final User currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    var token = await user.getIdToken();

    GoogleUser googleUser;
    OAuthToken oAuthToken;

    oAuthToken = OAuthToken(token, user.uid);
    googleUser = GoogleUser(user.email, user.displayName, null, oAuthToken);

    await API.getSocialLogin(googleUser).then(
      (result) async{
        if (result.code == 200) {
              String token = result.data.token.toString();
         await Helper.sharedPrefSaveData("token", token).then((onValue) {
            if (onValue) {
              isLoggedIn= true;
              print('logged in');
            }
          }).catchError((onError) {
            print('tokenSetError:$onError');
          });
        } else {
          isLoggedIn= false;
        }
      },
    ).catchError(
      (onError) {
        print('tokenError: $onError');
      },
    );
  }
  return isLoggedIn;
}

Future<void> signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();

  print("User Signed Out");
}

class OAuthToken {
  String token;
  String uId;

  OAuthToken(this.token, this.uId);

  factory OAuthToken.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return OAuthToken(json['token'] as String, json['uId'] as String);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['token'] = this.token;
    data['uId'] = this.uId;

    return data;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ ${this.token}, ${this.uId} }';
  }
}

class GoogleUser {
  String email;
  String firstName;
  String token;
  OAuthToken oAuthToken;

  GoogleUser(this.email, this.firstName, this.token, this.oAuthToken);

  factory GoogleUser.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return GoogleUser(json['email'] as String, json['firstName'] as String,
        json['token'] as String, OAuthToken.fromJson(json['oAuthToken']));
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['firstName'] = this.firstName;
    data['token'] = this.token;
    data['oAuthToken'] = this.oAuthToken;
    return data;
 }

 @override
 String toString() {
    return '{ ${this.email}, ${this.firstName}, ${this.oAuthToken} }';
 }
}
```

The Errors and warnings are :

```
I/zygote64(23850): Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=78KB
I/zygote64(23850): After code cache collection, code=112KB, data=65KB
W/ConnectionTracker(23850): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(23850): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@2774113
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1492)
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1648)
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:713)
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714051@20.47.14 (040408-0):1)
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714051@20.47.14 (040408-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at lu.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714051@20.47.14 (040408-0):9)
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at le.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714051@20.47.14 (040408-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at eg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714051@20.47.14 (040408-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker(23850):     at iz.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714051@20.47.14 (040408-0):5)
E/flutter (23850): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)
E/flutter (23850): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:582:7)
E/flutter (23850): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:18)
E/flutter (23850): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23850): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
E/flutter (23850): #3      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:359:49)
E/flutter (23850): #4      MethodChannelGoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in_platform_interface/src/method_channel_google_sign_in.dart:45:10)
E/flutter (23850): #5      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:233:42)
E/flutter (23850): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23850): #6      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:288:18)
E/flutter (23850): #7      GoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:359:9)
E/flutter (23850): #8      signInWithGoogle (package:restaurantapp/src/services/google-social-login.dart:18:70)
E/flutter (23850): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23850): #9      _SignInPage._signInButton.<anonymous closure> (package:restaurantapp/src/pages/signin_page.dart:222:15)
E/flutter (23850): #10     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
E/flutter (23850): #11     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
E/flutter (23850): #12     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
E/flutter (23850): #13     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:598:11)
E/flutter (23850): #14     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5)
E/flutter (23850): #15     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:222:7)
E/flutter (23850): #16     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:476:9)
E/flutter (23850): #17     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:77:12)
E/flutter (23850): #18     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
E/flutter (23850): #19     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter (23850): #20     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
E/flutter (23850): #21     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
E/flutter (23850): #22     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:358:19)
E/flutter (23850): #23     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:22)
E/flutter (23850): #24     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:267:11)
E/flutter (23850): #25     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
E/flutter (23850): #26     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:240:7)
E/flutter (23850): #27     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:213:7)
E/flutter (23850): #28     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (23850): #29     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (23850): #30     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (23850): #31     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
E/flutter (23850): #32     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
```

'''

Comment: have you run `flutter clean` then re-run it ?

Comment: I found the problem. Its with SHA1 key. I didnt configure it properly. Anyhow @Boby thanks for responding..